# OpenCV - detect components of certain width

Tags: opencv, image-processing, detection

I have an image with detected components. From this I need to detect components that form "polyline" of certain width (white and red in the image below).

What algorithm is best for this in OpenCV? I have tried separate all components one by one and use morphological operations but that was quite slow and not entirely accurate.

Note: the image below is downsampled. Original image has resolution 8K and border thickness is approx. 30-40px.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to always find the white and red shapes? Or you want to find shapes with a certain width? If the latter, you could get the area of each colour and the length of the medial axis of shapes of that colour and divide to get the mean thickness. Or work out a distance function from the medial axis and calculate mean or peak distance from that for mean/peak half-width.

Comment: this seems the work for Stroke Width Transform. There are several implementation out there, and it seems it will be [officially added](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/pull/2464) to OpenCV [text module](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/text/src)

Comment: @MarkSetchell I want to find shapes with a certain width.

Comment: @Miki Stroke Width Transform looks interesting, did not know this one :)

Comment: You refer to *"border thickness"*... what do you consider to be *"border"*?

Comment: How about trying something very simple like filtering contours with: (contour area)/ (contour perimeter/2) == desired width +- epsilon? This would give some false positives as well but might give a starting point to filter them further.

Comment: Could you down-scale the image again please but with nearest-neighbour interpolation? This one has 7,400 colours/classes.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have changed the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like your question - it is kind of like granulometry of lines instead of grains.

My approach is to find the unique colours in your image and then, for each colour:

- isolate that colour as white on black
- repeatedly erode by 3 pixels till nothing is left

Note that 20-30% of the code below is just for debug and explanation, and also that it could be speeded up with multi-processing and a little tweaking.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import medial_axis, erosion, disk

def getColoursAndCounts(im):
   """Returns list of unique colours in an image and their counts."""

   # Make a single 24-bit number for each pixel - it's faster
   f = np.dot(im.astype(np.uint32), [1,256,65536]) 
   # Count unique colours in image and how often they occur
   colours, counts = np.unique(f, return_counts=1)
   # Convert found colours back from 24-bit number to BGR
   return np.dstack((colours&255,(colours>>8)&255,colours>>16)).reshape((-1,3)), counts

if __name__ == "__main__":

   # Load image and get colours present and their counts
   im = cv2.imread('classes_fs.png',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
   colours, counts = getColoursAndCounts(im)

   # Iterate over unique colours/classes - this could easily be multi-processed
   for index, colour in enumerate(colours):
      b, g, r = colour
      count = counts[index]
      print(f'DEBUG: Processing class {index}, colour ({b},{g},{r}), area {count}')

      # Generate this class in white on a black background for processing
      m = np.where(np.all(im==[colour], axis=-1), 255, 0).astype(np.uint8)
      # Create debug image - can be omitted
      cv2.imwrite(f'class-{index}.png', m)

      # DEBUG only - show progression of erosion
      out = m.copy()

      # You could trim the excess black around the shape here to speed up morphology

      # Erode, repeatedly with disk of radius 3 to determine line width
      radius = 3
      selem = disk(radius)
      for j in range(1,7):
         # Erode again, see what's left
         m  = erosion(m,selem)
         c = cv2.countNonZero(m)
         percRem = int(c*100/count)
         print(f'   Iteration: {j}, nonZero: {c}, %remaining: {percRem}')
         # DEBUG only
         out = np.hstack((out, m))

         if c==0:
            break
      # DEBUG only
      cv2.imwrite(f'erosion-{index}.png', out)
```

So, the 35 unique colours in your image give rise to these classes once isolated:

[image]

Here is the output:

```
DEBUG: Processing class 0, colour (0,0,0), area 629800
   Iteration: 1, nonZero: 390312, %remaining: 61
   Iteration: 2, nonZero: 206418, %remaining: 32
   Iteration: 3, nonZero: 123643, %remaining: 19
   Iteration: 4, nonZero: 73434, %remaining: 11
   Iteration: 5, nonZero: 40059, %remaining: 6
   Iteration: 6, nonZero: 21975, %remaining: 3
DEBUG: Processing class 1, colour (10,14,0), area 5700
   Iteration: 1, nonZero: 2024, %remaining: 35
   Iteration: 2, nonZero: 38, %remaining: 0
   Iteration: 3, nonZero: 3, %remaining: 0
   Iteration: 4, nonZero: 0, %remaining: 0
...
...
DEBUG: Processing class 22, colour (174,41,180), area 3600
   Iteration: 1, nonZero: 1501, %remaining: 41
   Iteration: 2, nonZero: 222, %remaining: 6
   Iteration: 3, nonZero: 17, %remaining: 0
   Iteration: 4, nonZero: 0, %remaining: 0
DEBUG: Processing class 23, colour (241,11,185), area 200
   Iteration: 1, nonZero: 56, %remaining: 28
   Iteration: 2, nonZero: 0, %remaining: 0
DEBUG: Processing class 24, colour (247,23,185), area 44800
   Iteration: 1, nonZero: 38666, %remaining: 86
   Iteration: 2, nonZero: 32982, %remaining: 73
   Iteration: 3, nonZero: 27904, %remaining: 62
   Iteration: 4, nonZero: 23364, %remaining: 52
   Iteration: 5, nonZero: 19267, %remaining: 43
   Iteration: 6, nonZero: 15718, %remaining: 35
DEBUG: Processing class 25, colour (165,142,185), area 33800
   Iteration: 1, nonZero: 30506, %remaining: 90
   Iteration: 2, nonZero: 27554, %remaining: 81
   Iteration: 3, nonZero: 24970, %remaining: 73
   Iteration: 4, nonZero: 22603, %remaining: 66
   Iteration: 5, nonZero: 20351, %remaining: 60
   Iteration: 6, nonZero: 18206, %remaining: 53
DEBUG: Processing class 26, colour (26,147,198), area 2100
   Iteration: 1, nonZero: 913, %remaining: 43
   Iteration: 2, nonZero: 152, %remaining: 7
   Iteration: 3, nonZero: 12, %remaining: 0
   Iteration: 4, nonZero: 0, %remaining: 0
DEBUG: Processing class 27, colour (190,39,199), area 18500
   Iteration: 1, nonZero: 6265, %remaining: 33
   Iteration: 2, nonZero: 0, %remaining: 0
DEBUG: Processing class 28, colour (149,210,201), area 2200
   Iteration: 1, nonZero: 598, %remaining: 27
   Iteration: 2, nonZero: 0, %remaining: 0
DEBUG: Processing class 29, colour (188,169,216), area 10700
   Iteration: 1, nonZero: 9643, %remaining: 90
   Iteration: 2, nonZero: 8664, %remaining: 80
   Iteration: 3, nonZero: 7763, %remaining: 72
   Iteration: 4, nonZero: 6932, %remaining: 64
   Iteration: 5, nonZero: 6169, %remaining: 57
   Iteration: 6, nonZero: 5460, %remaining: 51
DEBUG: Processing class 30, colour (100,126,217), area 5624300
   Iteration: 1, nonZero: 5565713, %remaining: 98
   Iteration: 2, nonZero: 5511150, %remaining: 97
   Iteration: 3, nonZero: 5464286, %remaining: 97
   Iteration: 4, nonZero: 5420125, %remaining: 96
   Iteration: 5, nonZero: 5377851, %remaining: 95
   Iteration: 6, nonZero: 5337091, %remaining: 94
DEBUG: Processing class 31, colour (68,238,237), area 2100
   Iteration: 1, nonZero: 1446, %remaining: 68
   Iteration: 2, nonZero: 922, %remaining: 43
   Iteration: 3, nonZero: 589, %remaining: 28
   Iteration: 4, nonZero: 336, %remaining: 16
   Iteration: 5, nonZero: 151, %remaining: 7
   Iteration: 6, nonZero: 38, %remaining: 1
DEBUG: Processing class 32, colour (131,228,240), area 4000
   Iteration: 1, nonZero: 3358, %remaining: 83
   Iteration: 2, nonZero: 2788, %remaining: 69
   Iteration: 3, nonZero: 2290, %remaining: 57
   Iteration: 4, nonZero: 1866, %remaining: 46
   Iteration: 5, nonZero: 1490, %remaining: 37
   Iteration: 6, nonZero: 1154, %remaining: 28
DEBUG: Processing class 33, colour (0,0,255), area 8500
   Iteration: 1, nonZero: 6046, %remaining: 71
   Iteration: 2, nonZero: 3906, %remaining: 45
   Iteration: 3, nonZero: 2350, %remaining: 27
   Iteration: 4, nonZero: 1119, %remaining: 13
   Iteration: 5, nonZero: 194, %remaining: 2
   Iteration: 6, nonZero: 18, %remaining: 0
DEBUG: Processing class 34, colour (255,255,255), area 154300
   Iteration: 1, nonZero: 117393, %remaining: 76
   Iteration: 2, nonZero: 82930, %remaining: 53
   Iteration: 3, nonZero: 51625, %remaining: 33
   Iteration: 4, nonZero: 24842, %remaining: 16
   Iteration: 5, nonZero: 6967, %remaining: 4
   Iteration: 6, nonZero: 2020, %remaining: 1
```

If we look at class 34 - the one you are interested in. The successive erosions look like this - you can see the shape disappearing completely by a radius of around 15 pixels, which corresponds to losing 15 pixels on the left and 15 pixels on the right of your 30 pixel wide shape:

[image]

If you plot the percentage of pixels remaining after each successive erosion, you can easily see the difference between class 34 where it goes to zero after 5-6 erosions of 3 pixels each (i.e. 15-18 pixels) and class 25 where it doesn't:

[image]

**Notes**:

For anyone wishing to run my code, note that I up-scaled the input image (nearest-neighbour resampling) to 10x its current size with **ImageMagick**:

```
magick classes.png -scale 1000%x classes_fs.png
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed analysis. This solution works reasonably fo the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I mentioned this concept in my comment. One inelegant way to achieve this could be something like this:

```
_, ctrs, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
out = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")
epsilon = 1.0
desired_width = 30.0

for i in range(len(ctrs)):
    if(hierarchy[0][i][3] != -1):
        continue
    a = cv2.contourArea(ctrs[i])
    p = cv2.arcLength(ctrs[i], True)
    print(a, p)
    if a != 0 and p != 0 and abs(a/((p-2*desired_width)/2) - desired_width) < epsilon:
        cv2.drawContours(out, [ctrs[i]], -1, 255, -1)
```

A few parameters might need adjusting based on how opencv calculates area and perimeter.

EDIT: Adding a test image which has 4 squiggly lines with 14-16px width. Of course these are way too simplistic as compared to images you are dealing with.

[image]

Comment: @Martin Perry, I had error in my math. Corrected now. It would be interesting know if this gives you desired results to some extent.

Comment: I have tried it, but the result image is usually empty or only with fragments on other images that I have. The border thickness is +- same in all of them

Comment: In my tests and with the image you posted I am getting satisfactory results with a little tweak in epsilon value (note: there are a few false positives). What is your input to findContours? How are you binarizing it?

Comment: Input to find controus is my "colored" image converted to grayscale (for debug, I have checked generated contours and they are correct)

Comment: Hmmm...maybe you can test it on a test image by drawing a random curve in a binary form and run it with this method. I am adding a test image to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

1. Convert the image to bicolor. Objects are white, borders are black.
2. Erosion of all objects by 15-20 pixels. We get the marker.
3. Morphological reconstruction of the original image with a marker. You get an image without narrow lines.
4. Bitwise XOR paragraph 1 and 3.